# Spring @Autowired not working with configuration files across multiple projects

Tags: java, spring

I have different Java projects for `data`, `business` and `web` layer. I initialize the Spring context in the `web` layer and have all the Spring beans XML file(s) only in the `web` layer.

`@Autowired` feature works only for Spring beans in the `web` layer (and does not works for the Spring beans from the other two projects).

Do I need to define the Spring beans XML configuration in the other two projects (`data` and `business`) as well?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:jaxrs="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs" xmlns:cxf="http://cxf.apache.org/core"
    xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxrs.xsd
    http://cxf.apache.org/core http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/core.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx  http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <!-- Service -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.jai.mdm" />
    <context:annotation-config />

    <jaxrs:server id="mdmCxfServer" address="/">
        <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
            <ref bean="airlineService" />
        </jaxrs:serviceBeans>

        <jaxrs:extensionMappings>
            <entry key="json" value="application/json" />
        </jaxrs:extensionMappings>

        <jaxrs:providers>
            <bean class="com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJsonProvider" />
        </jaxrs:providers>

        <jaxrs:features>
            <cxf:logging />
        </jaxrs:features>
    </jaxrs:server>

    <!-- Business -@Autowired not working hence manual getter/setter old style used -->
    <bean id="airlineBusiness" class="com.jai.mdm.business.impl.AirlineBusinessImpl">
        <property name="airlineRepository" ref="airlineRepository" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Data -@Autowired not working hence manual getter/setter old style used -->
    <bean id="airlineRepository" class="com.jai.mdm.data.repository.impl.AirlineRepositoryImpl">
    </bean>

    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.jai.mdm.data.repository"  />

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" />
        <property name="url"
            value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/jaydb" />
        <property name="username" value="jay" />
        <property name="password" value="jay" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.jai.mdm.data" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
        </property>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven />
</beans>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

<display-name>mdm</display-name>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>


<servlet>
    <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Define _not working_. Are the fields `null`? Does it throw an exception? Provide an MCVE.

Comment: Would you mind sharing your Spring configuration file? Additionally, do you use multiple XML files? If so, across the three projects? And the last one: are you using Maven?

Comment: @ɐuıɥɔɐɯ - Thanks code added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my mistake... I have used the annotations ( like @Repository, @Service ) in the interface instead of the implementing class. After moving it to the class it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use a different Spring XML configuration file (or more depending on your needs) for every project. The JPA repositories, for instance, are used to be declared in your `data` project and imported whenever needed; the same for the others.

Have a look at the `import` from Spring.

I think you can have many configuration files in each project and be able to import them from `web` by using (the path `/META-INF/*` can be different):

```
<import resource="classpath:/META-INF/spring-context-data.xml" />
<import resource="classpath:/META-INF/spring-context-business.xml" />
```